# How can function return a cstring larger than char array it is filling?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I want to start off and explain that this is just a curiosity question to help me better understand c++.

I am working with the `cstring` library in C++ to generate a long cstring from multiple variables.  I was running a test program to see what the largest char array I would need to hold the cstring.  To do this I defined `buffer` as a global variable with a size that I knew would hold the cstring.  After generating it I used `strlen` to find the max length, which came out to 1517.  Then out of curiosity what it would look like when it failed, I reduced the size of `buffer` to 1000... and it still worked.  I didn't get an execution error until I reduced `buffer` to 300.

When I defined buffer in the `main()` function, I get the error when `buffer` is smaller than the output, but it still prints the full output.  I'm including my working example, I used the `gbuffer` and `buffer` for the global version of buffer and the local version of buffer.

my hypothesis is that the cstring gets written to the memory and `strcat` keeps writing past the bounds set when buffer or gbuffer are defined  and `std::cout` just reads until it hits the null char, so as long as nothing else reserves that space or is written there, the program still works out, though there is no guarantee that it will since it is writing in memory not reserved for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//Global Variables
int Temperature=100;
int Heat=100;
int Cool=100;
char Status[100]="Nothing";
char Source[100]="Default";
char gbuffer[900];

struct schedulePoint {
  uint8_t days = 12;
  uint8_t heat = 65;
  uint8_t cool = 85;
  uint16_t start = 60*24;
  uint16_t end = 60*24;
};

struct myData {
  char myName[12] = "TestStat";
  schedulePoint schedule[64];
  char password[25];
  char ssid[25] = "Wifi Thermostat";
  bool hidden = false;
  uint8_t defaultHeat = 65;
  uint8_t defaultCool = 85;
  int timezone = 0;
  char serverUName[25] = "";
  char serverPW[25] = "";
} data;


char * get_JSON(char * buff, unsigned int buffSize) {
  std::cout << "Buffer Size:" << buffSize << "\n";
  char convert[500];
  strcpy(convert,"<script>schedule=[");
  strcpy(buff,convert);
  for (uint8_t z = 0; z < 64; z++) {
    if (z == 0) strcat(buff, "[");
    else strcat(buff, ",[");
    sprintf(convert, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]", data.schedule[z].days, data.schedule[z].heat, data.schedule[z].cool, data.schedule[z].start, data.schedule[z].end);
    strcat(buff, convert);
  }
  strcat(buff, "];\n");
  sprintf(convert, "SSID=\"%s\";\n",data.ssid);
  strcat(buff, convert);;
  strcat(buff, "states=[\"Off\",\"Heating\",\"Cooling\"];\n");
  sprintf(convert, "stats={\"Temperature\":%d,\"State\":%s,\"Heat\":%d,\"Cool\":%d,\"Source\":\"%s\"};\n</script>", Temperature, Status, Heat, Cool, Source);
  strcat(buff, convert);
  return buff;
}


int main(){
        char buffer[1000];
        std::cout << get_JSON(gbuffer,sizeof(gbuffer));
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "Ouput Size:" << (unsigned)strlen(gbuffer);
        std::cout << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is like bowling without the lane bumpers. Nothing is going to stop you from writing outside the bounds of the array. And the worst part is, the program might still work. But at the end of the day, Undefined Behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my hypothesis is that the cstring gets written to the memory and strcat keeps writing past the bounds set when buffer or gbuffer are defined and std::cout just reads until it hits the null char, so as long as nothing else reserves that space or is written there, the program still works out, though there is no guarantee that it will since it is writing in memory not reserved for it.

Correct.

Your program's behaviour is undefined.

Don't do this.